# Import Passwords to Mediawiki 1.24.0

Tags: php, mediawiki, password-encryption

I have a database from an application with a lot of users I would like to migrate to a new mediawiki 1.24.0 installation.

My problem is to hash and match the passwords.

So I have a Password like `:special:3tvn09gpt4v5zu7ß3809mzn` and now I edited the `LocalSettings.php` by adding:

```
$wgPasswordConfig['special'] = array(
    'class' => 'SpecialPassword',
);
```

I put a `SpecialPassword.php` file inside `/includes/password/` and it contains

```
class SpecialPassword extends ParameterizedPassword {

    public function crypt( $plaintext ) {
        $this->args = array();
        $this->hash = $this->SpecialHash( $plaintext );
    }

    function SpecialHash( $plaintext ) {
        // .. //
    }
}
```

wehre `hash( $plaintext )` returns the hashed password.

But when I try to test I get

```
Class 'SpecialPassword' not found in .../includes/password/PasswordFactory.php on line 118`
```

So is this the right way to do it, and how to load my class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i had to add my class to the `wgAutoloadLocalClasses`